# Using CSS on elements created by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a select list that is created on a `.click` event. It looks like this:

```
$('<select class="selectStatus" onChange="statusSubmit()"/>')
    .attr('name', 'status')
    .append('<option>Pick one</option>', '<option>Open</option>', '<option>Full</option>', '<option>Canceled</option>')
    .appendTo(this);
```

In my main `styles.css` file I added this:

```
select .selectStatus {
    width:700px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Shouldn't the css be applied to this select list once it's created?

Comment: use Chrome's inspector to right click and `inspect element` method to see if the CSS is acting on the `<select>` typically you can find issues with typos or spaces.

Comment: I tried that and saw it wasn't being applied. I thought it was some type of issue with the DOM or something. Stupid typos! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are applying those styles to children of `select`s with `class="selectStatus"`.

Remove the space: `select.selectStatus`.